# Kafka: Can a single producer produce 2 different records to 2 different topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have two types of records, let's call it X and Y. I want record X to go to TopicX and record Y to go to TopicY.

1) Do I need two different producers?

2) Is it better to have 2 partitions instead of 2 different topics?

3) How can I avoid having two different producers for better network usage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

1. if you are using the same key/value serializer (and other producer properties), you can use the same producer. Producer record contains information about topic to be send
2. common practice is to have topic per message type. For partitionion some ids are used (clientId, sessionId... ). So, if records you want to send have different logic, than it is better to use different topics.